# Java: Matching array element and removing

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck on a few things with this program I need to do. Below, I am reading in two files, p1artists is the original file that I must read each line into an array and create a new Artist object. Each line in p1artists start with an artist ID (ex. 1-60) and their name. The second file, p2changes, has a file which specifies what Artist to delete or a new artist to add. The artists to be added simply are marked with "A" followed by their name. The artists to be deleted are followed by a "D" and only the artist ID.

My first issue that I noticed is that, when I print my artistList array at the end of my program, it only displays the last element/artist in the array. I want to be able to print the entire list. How would I be able to do that?

My second issue is within the second try-catch, where I try to delete the artist. I can't get the if-else statement to work. Any help or hints would be appreciated

My program thus far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialize total artists and id
    int totalArtist = 0;
    int newID = 0;

    //create an array for artists
    artist[] artistList = new artist[1 + totalArtist];

    //open the original file
    try {
        File file = new File("p1artists.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            int id = input.nextInt();
            String name = input.next();

            //create a new artist and put it in the array
            for (int i = 0; i < artistList.length; i++) {
                artistList[i] = new artist(id, name);
                totalArtist++;

            }
            //increment to a newID
            newID = id + 1;

        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    //open the file to be added/remove from original
    try {
        File file = new File("p2changes.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\t|\r\n");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            //read the first element of the line and check if it is A or D
            if (input.next().equals("A")) {
                String name = input.next();

                //add a new artist to the arraylist and increment newID
                for (int i = 0; i < artistList.length; i++) {
                    artistList[i] = new artist(newID, name);
                    newID++;
                    totalArtist++;

                }
            } else {
                int id = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(id);
                if (input.hasNext()) {
                   //go through array and find artist to be deleted
                    for (int i = 0; i < artistList.length; i++) {
                        if(artistList[i].getID() == id)
                            //remove artist from array list

                            //decrease total artists
                            totalArtist--;
                        else
                            System.out.println("Not working");

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A snippet p1artist looks like

```
1   Acconci
2   Ames
3   Aserty
4   Baron
```

A snippet what p2changes looks like

```
A   Reed
A   Rissman
D   3
A   Rogers
```

What output would look like

```
1  Acconci
2  Ames
4  Baron
5  Reed
6  Rissman
7  Rogers
```

Comment: could you give an example of what a entry in this file would look like

Comment: i edited my question and added what the files looked like

Comment: `artist[] artistList = new artist[1 + totalArtist];`....`totalArtist` is 0 at this point.

Comment: you could get around that by using an ArrayList, this way  you do not need to know the size of the file before hand

Comment: there are some other issues as well, why add artists that need to be deleted to the array list at all? If they are marked for deletion dont add them. This way when it comes time to write to the file you can just write the whole array List

Comment: this is an assignment that requires using single d arrays. as for your second comment, I don't believe I have added any artists-to-be-deleted in the artistList array at all. I have simply just read the file

Answer (score 0):

```
//initialize total artists and id
int totalArtist = 0;
int newID = 0;

//create an array for artists
artist[] artistList = new artist[1 + totalArtist];
```

I think you might have a problem with the array size. Although you do totalArtist++ or -- in your for loops when adding or deleting artists, the artistList array is alreay set with a size of 1 and will change based on the updated totalArtist number while the program executes.

Do you get any error with ArrayIndexOutOfBound?

Also I think you know this but if you want to print the whole array just for loop through every element and println() each element.

Comment: I don't get any array out of bounds error when I run this program. Also, I have tried printing every element in a forloop, but it only prints the last element.